# Flutter Android 12- Problem obtaining files

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I use `Flutter` to develop Android applications, and my `Android version is 12`. I read the built-in storage directory of Android and can see the directory, but I cannot see the files `txt, md, and PDF` are not available.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_app">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="flutter_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is how I fetch the list:

```
Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/docs');
List<FileSystemEntity> entities = dir.listSync(recursive: true);
```

My application `permissions` show that I have obtained the permission to read and write to mobile storage.

Comment: Have you defined file provider in manifest file?

Comment: I have edited the issue again, and now the XML file is complete. I don't think I have a definition. Do you have any examples to refer to?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44848

Settings > Privacy > Permission manager > Files and media and select your app and click Allowed for all files